# Sort axis aligned bounding boxes of meshes along a ray where each AABB is guaranteed to intersect the ray

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bounding-box

How do I sort axis aligned bounding boxes along a ray where each AABB is guaranteed to intersect the ray?

I have tried to sort the centroid's be that doesn't work well. So is there another alternative?

Comment: Can you clarify what it means to sort a set of bounding boxes  along a ray?

Comment: @ldog meaning the bounding boxes come in ray intersection order, from closest to the ray origin to farthest from the ray origin. (along the direction of the ray)

Comment: It still is not clear to me what you mean, can you update your question with an example of exactly what you are trying to compute.

Comment: I agree that the question isn't clear. Each BB has two points of intersection with the ray; one where it enters the box and another one where it leaves the box. (The ray does not necessarily pass the boxes' centroids.) I guess you want to sort the intersection points by distance from the origin. I also guess that the ray is not axis-aligned. Is your problem that you cannot find these intersection points? Also, is this a 2d or 3d problem?

Comment: What is unclear I do not see anything missing?

Comment: @Spektre: You are obviously a better mind reader than I am, but my intuition would have been to sort by the points where the ray enters (or perhaps exits) the boxes. Never mind.

Comment: For future reference this question is only clear as it is posted if one is familiar with computer 3d graphics. For example AABB is a common term apparently in that field. A lot of gaps in your question can be filled if one is familiar with this field, otherwise, you need to explain this in your question. And yes the trivial answer is point to ray/plane distance as stated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort by perpendicular distance from `ray_start` in `ray_direction` direction. That can be computed using simple `dot` product.

1. **If the AABB do not intersect you can sort by**

   ```
   dot(BBOX_center-ray_start,ray_direction)
   ```
2. **If AABB intersect**

   then you can use all the points of BBOX instead of center and chose the one with smallest dot result for sorting so sort by:

   ```
   min(
      dot(BBOX_p0-ray_start,ray_direction),
      dot(BBOX_p1-ray_start,ray_direction),
      dot(BBOX_p2-ray_start,ray_direction),
      dot(BBOX_p3-ray_start,ray_direction),
      dot(BBOX_p4-ray_start,ray_direction),
      dot(BBOX_p5-ray_start,ray_direction),
      dot(BBOX_p6-ray_start,ray_direction),
      dot(BBOX_p7-ray_start,ray_direction),
      )
   ```

   However putting AABB BBOXes in order does not mean objects will be hit in the same order! Also this sorts by first "hit" if you want the last hit then sort by `max` instead ...

   You might keep both (`min,max`) orders and use `O(n^2)` test for overlaps discrepances in order between the 2 sorts as majority of order should be the same just the intersecting BBOXes might have different local order where `n` is number of locally intersected BBOXes which is probably much smaller than the total number of BBOXes ...

Comment: Thanks! I think i may modify this further to store the end point of the current intersecting mesh (from bounding box). Then once you reach an AABB whose start is past the current intersecting AABB end, then I can stop.